# BigQuery data matching GA on daily basis but not over larger time frame

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am calculating Bounced sessions (sessions with only 1 pageview) via BQ.
Query is joining a table that gives me number of all sessions and a table that gives me bounced sessions.

When I run my query on just one specific date, my numbers match with the numbers in GA, but if I select bigger timeframe, for example a month, the numbers (only for Bounced sessions) are off. 
Also, if I run each subquery separately, I get correct numbers for any timeframe.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  A.date AS Date,
  A.Landing_Content_Group AS Landing_Content_Group,
  MAX(A.sessions) AS Sessions,
  MAX(B.Bounced_Sessions) AS Bounced_Sessions
FROM (
  SELECT
    date,
    hits.contentGroup.contentGroup2 AS Landing_Content_Group,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(visitStartTime AS string),fullVisitorId)) AS sessions
  FROM
    `122206032.ga_sessions_201808*`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE
    hits.type="PAGE"
    AND hits.isEntrance = TRUE
  GROUP BY
    date,
    Landing_Content_Group
  ORDER BY
    date DESC,
    sessions DESC ) A
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    date,
    hits.contentGroup.contentGroup2 AS Landing_Content_Group,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(visitStartTime AS string),fullVisitorId)) AS Bounced_Sessions
  FROM
    `122206032.ga_sessions_201808*`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE
    hits.type="PAGE"
    AND totals.pageviews = 1
    AND hits.isEntrance = TRUE
  GROUP BY
    date,
    Landing_Content_Group
  ORDER BY
    date DESC,
    Bounced_Sessions DESC ) B
ON
  a.Landing_Content_Group = b.Landing_Content_Group
GROUP BY
  Date,
  Landing_Content_Group
ORDER BY
  Date DESC,
  Sessions DESC
```

What I should get:

[GA results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu9ex.png)

What I get in BQ for that date when a time frame is a month:

[BQ results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0edNs.png)

I tried different JOINs and Aggregations but so far still in the unknown :)

Comment: Are you certain your GA results are not sampled? Generally speaking one would expect BigQuery results to be more accurate, as we are dealing with raw data, compared to GA?

Comment: The solution was to also join tables on date. Once I did that I got the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it, the solution was to also join the tables on the date.

```
ON
  a.date = b.date
  AND a.Landing_Content_Group = b.Landing_Content_Group
```